# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when destroying body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, box2d-iphone

I have created a method within the Sprite class that updates the position of a CCPhysicsSprite body till it reaches a certain position. Code below:

```
-(void)updatePhyscisSprite    {

if (phySpr.b2Body->GetPosition().y < 200.0/PTM_RATIO) {

    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0.0, 12.0*phySpr.b2Body->GetMass());
    phySpr.b2Body->ApplyForce(force, phySpr.b2Body->GetWorldCenter());
    }
if (phySpr.b2Body->GetPosition().y > 200.0/PTM_RATIO) {
    bWorld->DestroyBody(phySpr.b2Body);
    phySpr.b2Body = NULL;
    [bLayer removeChild:phySpr];

}
}
```

I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the line:

```
if (phySpr.b2Body != NULL) { // EXC_BAD_ACCESS ERROR
```

I have a feeling that checking for nullity when the body is NULL is creating the problem since the method is called every 1/60 of a second. I am not really sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: the phySpr is causing the crash, try niling the phySpr after removeChild

Comment: Give context for `if (phySpr.b2Body != NULL)`.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: It's working. thanks a lot. I've been at it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this :

in PhyscisSprite.mm

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    bWorld->DestroyBody(b2Body);
    b2Body = NULL;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

and in your function just type

```
[bLayer removeChild:phySpr cleanup:YES];
```